# Python BeautifulSoup Looping Through Table Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Very new to Python here. I'm trying to capture some data from this page [this page](https://us.diablo3.com/en/item/helm/). I'm trying to get the item name and the item type captured in two lists. I can figure out how to join them into one table later. Any help would be great!

The lines of code work on their own but the loop doesn't work for me.
This produces two lines of code successfully:

```
import urllib
import bs4 as bs

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://us.diablo3.com/en/item/helm/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

item_details =  soup.find('tbody')
print(item_details) 

item_name = item_details.find('div', class_='item-details').h3.a.text
print(item_name)

item_type = item_details.find('ul', class_='item-type').span.text
print(item_type)
```

This repeats the value of the first item_name over and over:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='item-details'):
    item_name = item_details.find('div', class_='item-details').h3.a.text
    print(item_name)
    item_type = item_details.find('ul', class_='item-type').span.text
    print(item_type)
```

This is the output:

```
Veil of Steel
Magic Helm
Veil of Steel
Magic Helm
Veil of Steel
Magic Helm
Veil of Steel
Magic Helm
Veil of Steel
Magic Helm
Veil of Steel
Magic Helm
Veil of Steel
Magic Helm
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `find_all` (returns list) instead of `find` (returns single element):

```
for i, j in zip(item_details.find_all('div', class_='item-details'), item_details.find_all('ul', class_='item-type')):
    print(i.h3.a.text, " - ", j.span.text)
```

The output is:

```
Veil of Steel  -  Magic Helm
Leoric's Crown  -  Legendary Helm
Harlequin Crest  -  Magic Helm
The Undead Crown  -  Magic Helm
...
```

or in more readable format:

```
names = item_details.find_all('div', class_='item-details')
types = item_details.find_all('ul', class_='item-type')

for name, type in zip(names, types):
    print(name.h3.a.text, " - ", type.span.text)
```

Comment: This is great! How do I show the results in a 2xn matrix instead of concatenating them?

Comment: @Lucas , how do you want output to look like? Can you share example?

Comment: I will ultimately export this to a csv file so I'd want to have two columns, one with item_name and all the values below, then one with item_type, and values below.

Comment: @Lucas, do you mean `name_list = [name.h3.a.text for name in names]` and `type_list = [type.span.text for type in types]`? This will return two separate lists of names and types

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is how can I get it in a format that is ready to be exported to a csv. The csv will contain two columns (like an excel file with two columns). Instead of printing the names, I want them written to a dataframe (?).

Comment: @Lucas , OK, I guess instead of `print(name.h3.a.text, " - ", type.span.text)` it should be something like `csv_writer.writerow([name.h3.a.text, type.span.text])`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one loop of the details section rather than saving them in different list and matched them up

```
item_details = []
for sections in soup.select('.item-details'):
    item_name = sections.select_one('h3[class*="subheader-"]').text.strip()  # partial match subheader-1, subheader-2, ....
    item_type = sections.select_one('ul[class="item-type"]').text.strip()
    item_details.append([item_name, item_type])

print(item_details)
```

output

> [['Veil of Steel', 'Magic Helm'], ["Leoric's Crown", 'Legendary Helm'], ....

Comment: Thanks for this Tobey. Also correct but the other answer makes a bit more intuitive sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://us.diablo3.com/en/item/helm/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

item_names = soup.find_all('div', class_='item-details')
for ele in item_names:
   print(ele.h3.a.text)

item_type = soup.find_all('ul', class_='item-type')
for ele in item_type:
    print(ele.span.text)
```

Why your code didn't work:

It looks like instead of iterating over all elements, your code kept fetching the same element (find_all for all elements).

Comment: Hey. You're answer wasn't posted when I started writing mine. I took some time to check if my code worked and I think you had posted your answer by that time. But yes it's almost the same.