# Python BeautifulSoup Extracting Data From Header

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, header

This is a follow-up from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238239/python-beautifulsoup-looping-through-table-data/54238403?noredirect=1#comment95302814_54238403). Thanks for the help so far.

I've got some code to loop through a page and create a dataframe. I'm trying to add a third piece of information but it is contained within the header so it's just returning blank. The level information contained in the td and h3 part of the code. It returns the error *"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"* If I change level.h3.text to level.h3 it will run but then it will have the full tags in the data frame, instead of just the number.

```
import urllib
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
#import csv as csv

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://us.diablo3.com/en/item/helm/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

item_details =  soup.find('tbody')

names = item_details.find_all('div', class_='item-details')
types = item_details.find_all('ul', class_='item-type')
#levels = item_details.find_all('h3', class_='subheader-3')
levels = item_details.find_all('td', class_='column-level align-center')
print(levels)

mytable = []



for name, type, level in zip(names, types, levels):
    mytable.append((name.h3.a.text, type.span.text, level.h3.text))



export = pd.DataFrame(mytable, columns=('Item', 'Type','Level'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your code as below:

```
for name, type, level in zip(names, types, levels):
    mytable.append((name.h3.a.text, type.span.text, level.h3.text if level.h3 else "No level"))
```

Now `"No level"` (you can use `"N/A"`, `None` or whatever you like the most) will be added as third value in case there is no level (no header)

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.